# IPV6 and MAC discovery

Tags: ipv6, mac-address

Is there a way to get the MAC and IPV6 Global link address for the network, just as ARP does with IPV4 in Ubuntu. I tried to retrieve IPV6(Link Local Address) using THC-IPV6 tool. But retrieving MAC is not possible.

Comment: Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP) provides equivalent functionality for IPv6 that ARP does for IPv4. Take a look at the output of `ip -6 neighbour` or in Windows `netsh interface ipv6  show neighbors`

Comment: ip -6 neighbour returned no results. IPV6 is disabled in my router. Only link local address is available.So I created  a local DHCPV6 server in one of my system, which will provide IPV6 to rest of the machines.Is it possible to implement NDP in C-language.Isn't that the THC-IPV6 tool based on NDP.

Answer (score 1):

`alive6` from the THC-IPv6 toolkit does not do the job, but right after a scan you may issue indeed `ip -6 neigh` as `alive6` will "wake up" all neighbors so that they will show up in the neighbor cache.

A cleaner way is to use `scan6` from the [IPv6 toolkit](http://www.si6networks.com/tools/ipv6toolkit/), `scan6 -i <if> -L -e -v` does what you look for.